# Make a div affect a precedent div on hover?

Tags: html, css

I know that you can make hovering over a div affect the div directly after it with '+' and any div after it with '~'. But I have a situation where I need a div directly before and after the div I'm hovering over to be affected. What I am trying to do is have 4 circles grow on hover (which works fine), and the adjacent circles should be pushed aside.

Here is a codepen that may make it more apparent what I am trying to do:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bojug

Here is a snippet of code with the issue.

```
#circ2:hover + #circ3{
   margin: 100px 0px 100px 8%; 
   }

#circ2:hover ~ #circ1{
   margin: 100px 2% 100px 13%;
   background: blue; 
   }
```

As you can see, when you hover over circle number 2, circle number 3 is pushed aside but circle number 1 is not. Does anyone have a way around this. I know some of you may suggest JS or JQuery which I am not familiar with. In that case could you point me in the right direction? Also, I know there are many threads that address similar issues but I havent seen one that asks about affecting preceding divs. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you make the codepen demo urself?

Comment: @Zword it's a follow up from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715437/make-a-div-grow-in-all-directions-with-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood from your question I think you want to shift the preceding elements like the post elements.

If I am correct, just use the simple technique .Shift parent relatively on hover  - >

```
#circles:hover{
    position:relative;
    right:40px;
}
```

### [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oHyql)

---

## Update with transition

```
#circles{
    position:relative;
    right:0px;
}
#circles:hover{
    position:relative;
    right:40px;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

### [Demo 2](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Izbln)

Comment: Somewhat, but I only want the adjacent circles to move, this method moves all 4 to the left. Also, is there anyway the shift could be a smooth transition rather than a flashing movement?

Comment: I did now, looks great! I didn't know to include the css info for just #circles without the hover, but now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm too lazy to change youre code, since it's quite big, but the following idea should help:

You have

```
#circ2:hover + #circ3 //Affects circ3, when circ2 is hoverd
```

Now you want to affect #circ1, when circ2 is hoverd.

Try this:

```
#circ1           //Set the rules you want to see applied when circ2 IS hovered
#circ1 + :not(:hover) //Set the standard style here.
```

That way, since #circ2 isn't ususally hovered, you see the standard style. But as soon as you hover over it, the :not()-selector will no longer apply - and the hover styles will apply.

Comment: I don't think this works because isn't the :not(:hover) based off "not hovering" on #circ2? So it should be #circ1 + #circ2:not(:hover). If this is the case the "//Set standard style here." will apply to #circ2 when it should apply to #circ1 right?

Comment: Argh, yes, you're right... apparently I was to tired when typing this. Now I'm intrigued by this problem, If you haven't solved it, I'll think somemore about it right now